# Drawing trees without any constraint on degrees

Tags: algorithm, tree, draw

I'm working on visualization of my distributed algorithm which solves problems on trees.

I have to draw a rooted tree which is given as an input.

Currently, I know how to handle the case if every node has at most 2 children. In this situation, for every node `v`, I draw `v` as a circle with coordinates `(x(v), x(y))`, where:

```
x(v) := index of v in the inorder traversal
y(v) := distance from v to the root
```

That works fine (of course the width of the tree is quite big, but that doesn't bother me much) but only for at most binary trees.

Please, suggest what algorithm I should use for general trees. The only requirement that I have is that the drawing has to be planar.

**EDIT:**

```
the simpler algorithm is to implement, the better
```

Comment: You might find this [link](http://billmill.org/pymag-trees/) useful. The m-ary tree case is discussed last in the article.

Comment: @rrufai Please post the comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. Will try to expand on it over time, so that it can be as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the article ["Drawing Presentable Trees"](http://billmill.org/pymag-trees/) by Bill Mill, the core steps of an m-ary tree drawing algorithm are the following:

> 1. Do a post-order traversal of the tree
> 2. If the node is a leaf, give it an x coordinate of 0
> 3. Otherwise, for each of its children, place the child as close to its left sibling as possible
> 4. Place the parent node halfway between its leftmost and rightmost children

The above steps have one problem though, the sub-trees to the left cause the rest of the tree to be pushed to the right and leads to imbalance. The article implements the following principle to solve the problem:

> Principle 6: The child nodes of a parent node should be evenly spaced.

There's a link to a [Python implementation](http://github.com/llimllib/pymag-trees/) of these steps given in the article.

Answer (score 3):

[This is a fairly well-known paper](http://research.microsoft.com/~akenn/fun/DrawingTrees.pdf) (as in, I managed to remember it) on drawing trees of any degree.

Much simpler, [an old blog post of mine](http://acooke.org/cute/ASCIIDispl0.html) that prints a tree in ASCII.  You could adapt that approach if you want something quick and dirty.

Comment: These are great links, but your answer is worth nothing without them. Please try to include a summary of the concepts to improve your answer.